# How to calculate difference between two dates (number of days) in Pine Script?

Tags: date, time, pine-script

How to calculate difference between two dates (number of days)?

Comment: Does Pine Script have a manual? What does it say? Did you try something? What was the problem?

Comment: Please, be more descriptive about the problem you had, and provide any partial solution you reached.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [timestamp()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_timestamp) function:

```
//@version=4
study("")
days = (timestamp(2020, 05, 28, 00, 00) - timestamp(2020, 05, 26, 12, 00)) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
plot(days)
```

[image]